# LTspice Half bridge current spikes

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, inverter, nmos

I simulated a half bridge with two NMOS and at every switching event a current spike up to 1.2 A in the voltage source V4 occurs. I used a resistor as load because with any inductive or capacitive load I would expect a spike because of the dead time between the MOSFETs.
Can the parastitic capacitance between Gate-Drain and Gate-Source be the reason or did I do something wrong in the simulation?
I know that the selected FETs are oversized but properly I need them for a higher load.

[image]

Schematic:

```
M1 Vsource Vg_HS Vnode Vnode IXFX90N30
M2 Vnode Vg_LS 0 0 IXFX90N30
V4 Vsource 0 100
R3 0 Vnode 1k
V1 Vg_HS Vnode PWL REPEAT FOREVER (0 5 0.00159999 5 0.0016 0 0.0033 0 0.0033000001 5) ENDREPEAT
V2 Vg_LS 0 PWL REPEAT FOREVER (0 0 0.001649999 0 0.00165 5 0.003249999 5 0.00325 0 0.0033 0) ENDREPEAT
.model NMOS NMOS
.model PMOS PMOS
.lib C:\Users\hamsn\Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\cmp\standard.mos
.tran 7m
.backanno
.end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can the parasitic capacitance between Gate-Drain and Gate-Source be the reason

Not quite. It's the Drain-Source capacitance.

If you check [the spec sheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/240/ixys_s_a0008598450_1-2273233.pdf), Coss is 1 nF at 100 V.

I eyeballed the switching time to be 0.1 ms. The supply voltage is 100 V.

I = CV / T = 1 nF * 100 V / 0.1 ms = 1 A

That is darn close to the 1.2 A that you see reported.

Comment: Many thanks! With a smaller FET and a slower slew rate it look much better